# Decomposition of a discontinuous orthogonal projector

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $P^2 = P^T = P:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ can be decomposed into $P(x) = P_1(x) + \cdots + P_a(x)$ where $P_i^2 = P_i^T = P_i$, $\mathrm{rank}(P_i) = 1$, $P_iP_j = 0$ if $i\neq j$, and $\sum_{i\in A} P_i(x)$ is discontinuous at $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$ for all $A \subseteq \{\,1,2,\dots,a\,\}$. Can we say anything about the decomposition $P(x) = P_c(x) + P_d(x)$ where $P_c(x)$ and $P_d(x)$ are orthogonal projectors that are continuous and discontinuous at $x_0$, respectively, and $P_cP_d = 0$?

Comment: It sounds like it is a way to build a "moving coordinate system". The sum of two would project on something which spans two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

We could think of an infinitesimally small thread, which at one point splits up into a 2D surface. Projecting along a one dimensional thread requires one dimension. But projecting along the surface requires two so at the point where the tread spreads out, a second $P$ would be needed to encode the local surface tangent.